# LWP with SSL and client certificates

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, protocols, lwp

Debian 10.  I try to connect to a remote server with certificate. However connection fails with 500 error. DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2593: global error: Failed to load certificate from file (no PEM, DER or PKCS12) error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag.
Same code with same certificate works fine with several Debian 9. I have tried different versions with Debian 10 - of IO-Socket_SSL (ex. 2.044 - 2.060), LWP-Protocol-https (ex. 6.05 - 6.07) with no luck.
For clear experiment I took fresh from provider debian images with 9 & 10. It works with basic perl modules with ver 9 and fails with ver 10.
I need a piece of help & advise , cause I'm loosing hope :(

```
use LWP;

    use LWP::UserAgent;
    use LWP::Protocol::https;
    use LWP::Debug qw(+);
    use Net::SSL;
    use IO::Socket::SSL qw(debug4);
        $ENV{HTTPS_CERT_FILE} = "cert.crt";
        $ENV{HTTPS_KEY_FILE}  = "private.key";
        $ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0;
    $ENV{HTTPS_DEBUG} = 1;
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    $ua->ssl_opts(
       SSL_verify_mode => 0,
       verify_hostname => 0,
       SSL_cert_file   => "cert.crt",
       SSL_key_file    => "private.key"
    );
    
        my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => "https://server:775/api");
        $req->header('content-type' => 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="http://tempuri.org/ICodeRequestOnline/GetProtocolVersion"');
        my $txt= qq{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope>...</soap:Envelope>};
        $req->content($txt);
        my $resp = $ua->request($req);
        print $resp->as_string;
```

Comment: The error message indicates that something is wrong with your `cert.crt`. Nothing is known about this file though.

Comment: Yeah, I have a feeling that it is a matter of cert itself.
 Well, if cert.crt is corrupted it won't work with Debian 9. However it does work just fine out of the box even on newly created VM with basic list of required perl modules. I contacted people who issued this cert, they have given me an hint: cert uses SHA-1 which is outdated by now. openssl should operate with  SSL_CTX_set_security_level=0 control. Is there a way to use something similar to this param to make LWP deal with this cert?

Comment: Try to set `SSL_cipher_list` to `DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1`

Comment: any idea where to set that parameter?

Comment: Same place where the other `SSL_*` parameters where set, i.e. `ssl_opts`.

Comment: No reaction. I don't think it reads SSL_cipher_list from there... 
I use IO::Socket::SSL version 2.060
LWP::Protocol::https version 6.07

Comment: I have tried to edit /etc/ssl/openssl.conf: CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1 , but thay had no result...

Comment: All of a sudden I solved it! It is a bad practice and probably a security trouble... 
I failed to find how to force NET:SSL downgrade security requirements. So I did it at /etc/ssl/openssl.conf.  I ahve changed CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1   
 (was 2 by default) and MinProtocol from TLSv1.2 to TLSv1.0

Comment: If someone knows how to get same results without global changes in /etc/ssl/openssl.conf - please let me know.